# Integration of a polynomial about a cricle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...+a_nz^n$ $(a_n \neq0)$. Show that for sufficiently large r, $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C(0,r)}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz=n$$

What can be said about a small r?

I am trying to manipulate Cauchy's formula to achieve what I need but I can not seem to reach the conclusion. Also wouldn't the answer be the same for any positive r no matter the size?

Comment: Try writing $p(z)$ as $a_n(z - w_1)\dots(z - w_n)$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\;w_1,...,w_n\;$ are the roots of the polynomial, then

$$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{z-w_k}$$

since all the roots are within a circle of radius $\;r\;$ big enough, we get that here that taking little circles $\;C_{r_k}\;$ about $\;w_k\;$ :

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{C_r}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz=\frac1{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^n\oint_{C_{r_k}}\frac{dz}{z-w_k}=\frac1{2\pi i}\sum_{k=1}^n2\pi i=n$$

Formally, the above works "only" for simple roots, but in fact if a root is of multiplicity $\;m\;$ , then you'd get for that factor that

$$\frac{((z-w)^m)'}{(z-w)^m}=\frac m{z-w}$$

and again  in the integral about $\;w\;$ you "count" that root $\;m\;$ times.

Comment: $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \sum_k \frac{1}{z-w_k}$ is always valid, if $\{w_k\}$ are the (possibly repeated) roots

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you. Indeed, but as the proof was presented, some question could be asked about what happens to the integrals: do we have to integrate several times the same thing? Yes, but this can be confusing in my opinion. It is clearer, I think, to gather together all the equal roots and do as shown in the last part.

Comment: @Joanpermo : in the same way (don't know if you knew it) if $h(z)$ is an entire function, then $\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} = g'(z)+ \sum_k \left( \frac{1}{z-\omega_k} + \frac{1}{\omega_k}\right)$ where $g'(z)$ is an entire function and $\omega_k$ are the (possibly repeated) roots

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you, that's interesting. Do you have any reference for this material?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem (and the $\frac{1}{w_k}$ term is just there to ensure convergence in some cases)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $R>|z_M|$ , where $z_M$ is the root of $p(z)$ with the largest magnitude.  For $|z|>R$, we have

$$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=n\frac 1z+O\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)$$

Then, integrate over a circle with radius $R'\ge R$.